# Calculations with different datatypes in CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I am making some CRM plug-in using C#.

I have variable a containing Whole Number(`Format: None`), that should represent discount percent, it is limited from `0 to 100`.

There is variable `b` that is Currency and represents Price.

I should count Final Price as `Price - Discount`, and put the result in variable `c`, that is also Currency

Is it possible to do

```
c = b*(100-a)/100;
```

Or there is some conversion to do?

Comment: If there are information missing let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking for Dynamics CRM with a generic calculation, the only thing you need to take care is accessing the right value from your input variable.

In your case the b variable is a currency, meaning that probably is a Money type, so you will get the value from the Value property that is a decimal type.